# Decompress a GZipped response from the server (Socket)

Tags: c#-3.0

Umm, ok, after sending some data to the server, noting this particular part:

```
"Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n"
```

I am getting the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 09 Apr 2010 23:25:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.8
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Apr 2010 23:25:27 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding

7aa
??U-?Rh?%?2?w??PM]??7?qZ?K?)???2?&??m???"q??/p9w?????x?[`tA!G???G?5z??????a>k????????Q
???N??
('??f?,(??Y:5B???-?)?3x^0e:j?`,???**???F>G)?2????@???b??????A?k???Ar?n?
```

But how do I decompress it? Note that I am using the Socket Class to do all the work.

I know how to decompress it, but the problem here lies in the fact that I cannot separate the Packet from the GZipped data, psuedo-psuedocode (or whatever) on how I do it:

```
Socket sends packet;
Socket reads response from server, stores into a ByteArray;
Create MemoryStream, use ByteArray;
Create GZipStream, use Memorystream;
```

now the problem occurs; I am getting the following Error:

> **System.IO.InvalidDataException** 
>   The magic number in GZip header is not
>   correct. Make sure you are passing in
>   a GZip stream.

I hope the explanation is clear enough >__>.

Comment: Check your bytearray against whats on the wire using wireshark.

Comment: I cannot find anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

The content that you need to gzip begins after a double-newline, and goes for (if present) Content-Length bytes. You might start there.

Is it possible for you to use `System.Web.HttpRequest`? It will take care of a lot of the administrative details of parsing the response for you...

Or do you have to use raw Sockets?

Comment: I tried converting the response directly to a string and split it using "\r\n\r\n" and convert it back to a byte array etc. but it didn't work. Also the response I am showing is one of the x different ones, meaning; the response is different every time.

I can use the HttpWebRequest, but I don't want to (since I already know how to). I want to do it using the Socket Class only. The whole point of this is for me to learn how to do things using the Socket Class rather than the HttpWebRequest or TcpClient.

Comment: Entirely possible that the byte[]->string->byte[] round trip failed failed due to encoding issues. Can you try converting it and converting it back without doing the split in between? If the strings aren't identical, I can think of some more things to try.

Comment: Apparently the strings are identical.

psuedo-psuedocode:
Receive response, store in ByteArray[];
Convert to string A;
Convert to ByteArray[];
Convert to string B;
Check string A with B.. if (A == B) { Console.Write("Ok.") };