# Easiest way to serialize data between C# and Android app

Tags: c#, android, serialization

I have a desktop application written in C# that will communicate with an Android app. What is the easiest way to pass data between them over a tcp/ip connection? I'm less interested in performance, more interested in ease of implementation.

Comment: I suggest gzipstream over socket.
see:

[gzipstream for forward only stream over sockets][1]

[Using GZipStream for Client/Server Async Communication][2]

[Decompress a GZipped response from the server (Socket)][3]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050015/gzipstream-for-forward-only-stream-over-sockets
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922206/using-gzipstream-for-client-server-async-communication
  [3]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619058/decompress-a-gzipped-response-from-the-server-socket

Comment: For ease of use, I would suggest serializing to JSON or similar and passing messages. I don't have any Android experience, but I can only assume there are dozens of JSON de/serialization libraries out there.

Comment: I agree with @MikeCaron. If you don't need to serialize binary data, JSON is really simple on the Android side. Use the GSON library (Google's JSON library).

Answer (score 2):

I naturally don't understand you by the meaning of **`ease of implementation`**. But as I guessed, you should need these:

**`In [C#]:`**

```
//util function
public static void WriteBuffer(BinaryWriter os, byte[] array) {
            if ((array!=null) && (array.Length > 0) && (array.Length < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
                WriteInt(os,array.Length);
                os.Write(array);
            } else {
                WriteEmptyBuffer(os);
            }
        }

//write a string
public static void WriteString(BinaryWriter os, string value)  {
            if (value!=null) {
                byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
                WriteBuffer(os,array);
            } else {
                WriteEmptyBuffer(os);
            }
        }
```

**`In [Java] Android:`**

```
/** Read a String from the wire.  Strings are represented by
 a length first, then a sequence of Unicode bytes. */
public static String ReadString(DataInputStream input_stream) throws IOException  
{
    String ret = null;
    int len = ReadInt(input_stream);
    if ((len == 0) || (len > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
        ret = "";
    } else {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        input_stream.readFully(buffer);
        ret = new String(buffer, DATA_CHARSET);
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

For further structural data, For e.g you want to send objects between C# and Java, please use **`XML Serialization in C#`** and **`XML Parser in Java`**. You can search for these on Internet; many examples are on [**Code Project**](https://www.codeproject.com/) website.

In Android part, you can use **[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html)** library for ease of use.